# Question about the transpose of identity and hat matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, idempotents

So I know that because the hat matrix and identity matrix are both symmetric,

$H^{T}=H$ and $I^{T}=I$, respectively

so would $(I-H)^{T}=(I-H)$? Sorry if the answer is obvious, I am missing a step in a proof and I do not have much background in linear algebra. Thanks for the help.

edit: replaced "idempotent" with "symmetric"

Comment: A matrix with $A^T=A$ is symmetric, not idempotent. In general $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$ etc.

Comment: Whoops, just realized I mixed up two lines in the course notes, H^n=H regards idempotency...

Guess that highlights how little linear algebra I know. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

We know that $(A-B)^T = A^T - B^T$. This means $$(I-H)^T = I^T - H^T $$
A Hat matrix is symmetric and so is the identity matrix so
$$ (I-H)^T = I - H $$